# Dividing bootstrap column under col-1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I would like to be able to divide a bootstrap gid even more. Without to much hassle or workarounds. What is the best way of creating column 1/24 of a grid.

[image]

Fiddle to understand better what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmm1ra7d/

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-xs-8">8/12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">4/12</div>
</div>

<br/>
Now I need to transform this to  a 0.5/12 => 1/24 What would be the best approach without a hacky fix. Also not to break the responsiveness.
This is the smallest column bootstrap can make 8.3333%
<br/>
<br/>

<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1/12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">11/12</div>
</div>


<br/>
What I really want would be 4%
<br/>
<br/>

<div class='row'>
    <div style="width:3%; display: inline-block;">1/24</div><div style="width:96%;display: inline-block;">23/24</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just nest another column setup in the `col-*-1`. If the padding on the nested row/columns is unwanted you can just add a class to override the padding.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can nest a row in a column, so basically you divide your main row in other rows. For example

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <!-- now you have 1/4 -->
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <!-- now you have 1/4 of 1/4 -->
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```